# Lazarus antes de pesquisar tem que fazer commit

Tags: lazarus

Já passaram por isso? Se eu tenho uma consulta, e o resultado pode sofrer mudança de programas de terceiros o lazarus não vê essa mudança a menos que antes da pesquisa seja feita o commit e depois a pesquisa. Seguinte cenário:
Imaginamos que na primeira pesquisa no Lazarus ele ache o registro, antes de fazer novamente a mesma pesquisa o registro é deletado por alguém, ao realizar a segunda pesquisa o lazarus ainda acha o registro.

Existe outra forma de contornar que não seja antes da pesquisa dar commit?

Comment: Que sistema lazarento! Sério agora, eu acho que isso é comum em qualquer sistema que trabalhe com commits, não? No Git enquanto eu não realizar um merge do meu trabalho, ninguém mais vê o que eu alterei também...

Comment: @Renan no delphi funciona diferente, se o registro for excluído por fora do programa, na segunda consulta ele não acha.